# Assigning value to array in for loop

Tags: java

**So I have to do the following:**

"Declare one hundred numbers in a Java program, compute their average, and find out how many numbers are above the average."

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] list = new double[100];
        int x = 1;

        while(x<=100){
            for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
                list[i] = x;
            }
            x++;
        }

         double sum = 0;
         int j = 0;
         double average = 0;
         while(j < list.length){
            sum += list[j]; 

            average = sum / list.length; 
            j++;
         }
         for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
                if(list[i] > average){
                     System.out.println(list[i] + "is larger than the average");    
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The problem from what I can see is with assigning all the numbers up to 100 to the `list` array. When I check the list array for some reason I only have the number 100 for all the keys.

Comment: Your are overwriting the list in each iteration of `x`, since `x` goes up to 100, the last iteration will set each element of `list` to 100.

Comment: Change the assignment to `list[i] = i;` and remove the `while`loop.

Comment: also, determine the average OUTSIDE the summation loop.

Comment: If you have all numbers from 1 through 100, it can be simplified a lot. First you can use a math formula (n(n+1)/2) to find the sum, instead of iterating and find the average straight away by dividing the sum by the array length. No need to have so many loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you can do this with one liners:

- numbers: `final int[] numbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).toArray();`
- average: `final double average = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).average().getAsDouble();`
- above average: `final int[] aboveAverageNumbers = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).filter(number -> number > average).toArray();`

Although it's not optimal solution, but looks cool :)

Have in mind that using optionals you want to check if it is present.
Also I've repeated myself creating `IntStream`, which doesn't look pretty, but I couldn't reuse the same stream twice - I've suggest to read about this as well.
If you don't want to create it the same way you can use `IntStream.of(numbers)` instead of `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)` in the second and third example.

**WHAT YOU DID WRONG AND WHY**

In this loops:

```
double[] list = new double[100];
int x = 1;
while(x<=100){
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        list[i] = x;
    }
    x++;
}
```

There is a root of all evil. In `while` loop you are iterating from 1 to 100.
Inside you are iterating from 0 to 100.
In first step of your while loop you are assigning for all values in list 1.
Do you see this?

In the second step of your `while` loop, you are making another `for` loop for whole list. So now you are assigning for every field value 2. Etc...
This way your list contain on each cell value equals 100 - the last step of your `while` loop.

One loop would be enough, eg.

```
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++){
    list[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: There where many useful answers but yours helped me easily understand why I did it wrong thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `while` loop, it will make each index of your array contain the same value, so just replace this loop

```
    while(x<=100){
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
            list[i] = x;
        }
        x++;
    }
```

with this loop

```
    for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
        list[i] = i+1;
    }
```

or better yet :

```
    for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
        list[i] = i+1;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a for loop inside your while loop. This means that when x is 100, the for loop will fill the array with 100.
There is no need for the while loop. Try

```
  for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)    
    {    
         list[i] = i+1;   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you got two loops but you only need one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] list = new double[100];

        for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
            list[i] = i+1;
        }


        double sum = 0;

        for(double d : list){
            sum += d; 
        }

        double average = sum/list.length;

        for(double d : list){
            if(d > average){
                System.out.println(d + " is larger than the average");    
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have an arithmetic sequence, no need to iterate through the array again to find the sum. Use the formula, in your case it is: `(n*(n+1))/2`. If it's not an arithmetic sequence, again find the `sum` while you are assigning the values to the array.

Here's your simplified code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] list = new double[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        list[i] = (i + 1);
    }
    double sum = (100 * 101) / 2;
    double average = sum / list.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (list[i] > average) {
            System.out.println(list[i] + " is larger than the average");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** In case you want to assign random numbers to the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] list = new double[100];
    Random rand = new Random();
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        list[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
        sum += list[i];
    }
    double average = sum / list.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (list[i] > average) {
            System.out.println(list[i] + " is larger than the average");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confused. Let us separate the problems with methods

```
public class Main {

    public static int[] getArray(int size) {
        int[] output = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            output[i] = i + 1;
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static double avg(int[] input) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            sum += input[i];
        }        
        return sum / input.length; //Do not call this with an empty array
    }

    public static double largerCount(int[] input) {
        int larger = 0;
        double average = avg(input);
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (input[i] > average) {
                larger++;
            }
        }
        return larger;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] input = getArray(100);
        System.out.println(largerCount(input) + " elements are larger than the average of " + avg(input));
    }
}
```

This way the code is easier to understand and your work is simplified.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nested loop inside the while loop. For x, (0-100) the items in the array will be updated. In the last outer loop where x = 100, the array will have for all the values 100

Answer (score 0):

it can be done in this simple way :

```
int[] list = new int[100];
int sum = 0;
double average = 0;
 for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
     list[i] = i+1;
     sum = sum + list[i];
 }
  average = (double) sum / list.length; // casting to double 
 for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++){
      if(list[i] > average){
         System.out.println(list[i] + " is larger than the average");
      }
 }
```

link to output : https://ideone.com/24VpYO

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = new int[100];
        int x = 1;

        while (x <= 100) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                list[i] = x;
                x++;
            }
        }

        double sum = 0;
        int j = 0;
        double average = 0;
        while (j < list.length) {
            sum += list[j];
            j++;
        }
        average = sum / list.length;

        System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
        System.out.println("Avg:" + average);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            if (list[i] > average) {
                System.out.println(list[i] + "is larger than the average");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```